# Authenticate Appstore Connect API for Apple Enterprise Account

Tags: ios, jwt, app-store, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

Is there a way to authenticate the App Store connect API for apple enterprise account? There is no option available for apple enterprise account to generate the keys in appstoreconnect portal?

I need to pull bulk provisioning profiles from the enterprise account for CI/CD automation to automate signing enterprise apps?